# New Theorem: Custom Title

Tags: beamer

*Possibly a duplicate.. I'm sorry if so.*

**Problem**

Given the `beamer` class.

Is it possible to define a new theorem environment with title: "Type (Optional)"

**Example**

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newtheorem{type}{Type}
\newenvironment<>{type}[1]{\begin{block}#2{#1}}{\end{block}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{type}
Theorem Text
\end{type}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There's a missing `\end{document}`

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newtheorem{type}{Type}
\newenvironment<>{type}[2][]{%
  \begin{block}#3{#2\ #1}%
    \par%
  }{%
  \end{block}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{type}<1>[(explained)]{Type A}
Theorem Text
\end{type}%
\begin{type}<2>{Type B}
Other Text
\end{type}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]